# How to detect touch in spritekit?

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit, touch

I have a sprite and I would like to print some text if that sprite is pressed on.
Every tutorial that I have found on that seems to be outdated.
How is this possible?

It should be something like this:

```
if Sprite is touched {
    print("Some Text")
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have a custom class for your Sprite just override the `touchesBegan` method

Example

```
class Player: SKSpriteNode {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        userInteractionEnabled = true
    }
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        print("Did touch Player sprite")
    }
}
```

> Don't forget to set `userInteractionEnabled = true`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say that i don't have different classes for sprites and wouldn't want to have. Is there a way to do it in a class that has many sprites but i want only 1 to be clickable

Comment: @Asphys: The you should set `userInteractionEnabled = false` for the sprites you don't want to touch. Next into your `Scene.touchesBegan#withEvent#` you should find the node on the same position of your touch `let node = nodeAtPoint(touch.locationInNode(self))`

Answer (score 1):

In the touchesBegan function or touchesEnded you can add this code

```
for touch: AnyObject in touches {
      let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
      if sprite.containsPoint(location) {
         print("Some Text")
      }
}
```